# UniversalLink is not working in iOS 14 devices

Tags: ios, swift

[this is what I added in capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI1HS.png)I have an app that support the UniversalLink. But It failed to work on the iOS 14. Instead of open the app, it's routing to web. followed the same steps as given in other articles but still facing the same issue. Please send your suggestions for this.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }
    
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        UIApplication.shared,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: nil,
        annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
    )

}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)
{
    print("Continue User Activity called: ")
    
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb
    {
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL
        {
            "\(url.absoluteString)".printOn()
            
            if url.absoluteString == WebserviceCall_Swift.universal_url + "deposit-balance" //navigate to payment screen
            {
                Singleton.shared.strNavScreensUniversal = "deposit"
                
                let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
                
                if let mySceneDelegate : SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)
                {
                    let rootViewController = mySceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                    
                    if !Singleton.isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: Singleton.USERINFO)
                    {
                        let vc : LoginVC = BaseApp.sharedInstance.getViewController(storyboardName:StoryboardType.main.rawValue, viewControllerName: LoginVC.nameOfClass)

                        rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.setLoginData()

                        let vc : CustomTabbarController = BaseApp.sharedInstance.getViewController(storyboardName: StoryboardType.main.rawValue, viewControllerName: CustomTabbarController.nameOfClass)
                        
                        //AppDelegate.shared().mainNavBar.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true)
                        rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }
            else if url.absoluteString == WebserviceCall_Swift.universal_url + "contest" //navigate to payment screen
            {
                Singleton.shared.strNavScreensUniversal = "contest"
                
                let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
                
                if let mySceneDelegate : SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)
                {
                    let rootViewController = mySceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                    
                    if !Singleton.isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: Singleton.USERINFO)
                    {
                        let vc : CustomTabbarController = BaseApp.sharedInstance.getViewController(storyboardName: StoryboardType.main.rawValue, viewControllerName: CustomTabbarController.nameOfClass)

                        rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.setLoginData()

                        let vc : CustomTabbarController = BaseApp.sharedInstance.getViewController(storyboardName: StoryboardType.main.rawValue, viewControllerName: CustomTabbarController.nameOfClass)
                        
                        //AppDelegate.shared().mainNavBar.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true)
                        rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                let arrParams = url.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "/")
                
                if Singleton.isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: Singleton.USERINFO)
                {
                    self.setLoginData()
                }
                Singleton.shared.strNavScreensUniversal = "indv"
                Singleton.shared.contestID = "\(arrParams.last ?? "")"

                let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
                
                if let mySceneDelegate : SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)
                {
                    let rootViewController = mySceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                    
                    let vc : CustomTabbarController = BaseApp.sharedInstance.getViewController(storyboardName: StoryboardType.main.rawValue, viewControllerName: CustomTabbarController.nameOfClass)
                    
                    //AppDelegate.shared().mainNavBar.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true)
                    rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

                }
                
                
                "contest id == \(arrParams.last ?? "nil")".printOn()
            }
            
            var parameters: [String: String] = [:]
            
            URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.queryItems?.forEach
            {
                parameters[$0.name] = $0.value
            }
        }
        //handle url and open whatever page you want to open.
    }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    
    if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first
    {
        if Singleton.shared.strNavScreensUniversal != ""
        {
            return
        }
      self.scene(scene, continue: userActivity)
    }

    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
    // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
    // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
    // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)
{
        AppsFlyerLib.shared().start()
        // ...
    
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
}

func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
    // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
}

func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
    // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
    // to restore the scene back to its current state.
}
func setLoginData()
{
    let dicTemp = Singleton.getUserInfoFromUserdefault(withKey: Singleton.USERINFO)
    let dicDetails = dicTemp.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary
    "user id -------\(dicTemp)".printOn()
    Singleton.shared.USERID = "\(dicDetails.value(forKey: "_id") ?? "")"
    Singleton.shared.USERTOKEN = "\(dicDetails.value(forKey: "token") ?? "")"
    Singleton.shared.isLoggedIn = true
    
}
//MARK:Get contest details
func contests_single(contest_id:String)
 {
     let dict = [
         
         "contest_id":contest_id,
         "user_id":Singleton.shared.USERID,
     ]
     Loader.sharedInstance.showLoader(msg: Constants.PLEASE_WAIT )// Start
     let service = WebserviceCall_Swift()
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
         service.callServiceWith(parameterDict: dict ,isAuth:true, url: "\(Constants.contests_single)" ,type:"POST", onCompletion: { (sender) in
             DispatchQueue.main.async
                 {
                     Loader.sharedInstance.stopLoader()
                     "Loader Close----------------------------".printOn()
                     if sender.isKind(of: NSString.self)
                     {
                         let error = sender as! String
                         if error == Constants.No_Internet
                         {
                             Singleton.actionShowNetwotkError(compblock: { (txt) in
                                 if txt == "Retry"
                                 {
                                    self.contests_single(contest_id: contest_id)
                                 }
                             })
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             Singleton.actionShowMessage(message: Constants.SomethingWentWrong)
                             
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         let arrResult = sender as! NSArray
                         let json = arrResult.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
                         if Int("\(json.object(forKey: "status") ?? "0")") == 200
                         {
                             "Data is \(json)".printOn()
                             "get single contest Api response \(json.value(forKey: "data") ?? "")".printOn()
                            
                         }
                         else if Int("\(json.object(forKey: "status") ?? "0")") == 201
                         {
                            Singleton.actionShowMessage(message: "\(json.object(forKey: "message") ?? "0")")

                         }else if Int("\(json.object(forKey: "status") ?? "0")") == 401
                         {
                             AlertViewS.ShowAlertTitle(AlertTitle: "", Message: "\(json.object(forKey: "message") ?? "")", ThemeColor: [ AppDelegate.shared().APP_COLOR], BtnAlignmentType: .Horizontal, ButtonOfArrayInString: ["OK"])
                             { (result) in
                                 
                                 if result == "OK"
                                 {
                                     AppDelegate.shared().logout()
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             Singleton.actionShowMessage(message: Constants.SomethingWentWrong)
                         }
                     }
             }
         })
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please send what you have done in code for this.

Comment: Can you just swipe down in that webpage and see whether there is a banner which shows option to open in your app ?

Comment: Hey i have added the code and the screenshot of capabilities in question